# Keith Wood JQuery SVG: the SVG does not drawn in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have trying to draw an svg image inside one of the table cells, however it dose not work at all. I see the div but without the svg image.
It is working if I create the div from html code () but from the javascript it does not work..
How can I draw the SVG from the javascript code
the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">

    <style type="text/css">
      @import "jquery/jquery.svg.css";
      #svgbasics { width: 400px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #247; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.svg.js"></script>

  <script src="InitialSVG.js"></script>
    <script src="draw.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #ffefdb;">


    <table id="GTable" style="width: 100%; background-color: white;" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 152px;">ID</td>
          <td style="margin-left: 18px; width: 150px;">Gene description ( name )</td>
          <td style="width: 152px; "> model</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </body>
</html>
```

here is the code : ( draw.js)// this function is called repeatedly on other function to create the table dynamically, I remove the loop but the same problem happens.

```
onLoad : function addRow(tableID ,Name, ID) {


            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 // first col
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML= ID;

 //secnd
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = Name;
 //third

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id="svgbasics";
            div.style.width = "400px";
            div.style.height = "400px";
            cell3.appendChild(div);

        }
```

( InitialSVG.js)

```
$(function() {
    $('#svgbasics').svg({onLoad: drawInitial});
  });

      function drawInitial(svg) {
    svg.rect(150, 50, 100, 50, 10, 10, {fill:'green'}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you add more than one row. Therefore, it looks as if you should give each row's DIV its unique id. Also, the script block *InitialSVG.js* is loaded **before** *draw.js*.  Try switching them.

e.g.

```
div.id="svgbasics"+rowCount
```

Or

```
div.id="Div"+ID
```